# How to display RGB color picked up from Json in React.js?

Tags: reactjs, json

I write the code like below,
I got the color data by integer like this.

255255255

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BDjE.png)

However, I want to show like the picture below

(how I call this? color something? it's not color picker)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKdfR.jpg)

The picture is the screen of the mobile app, and I would like the web app to have the same design as the mobile app as much as possible.

Is such an expression possible in React.js?

If it is possible,
how?

Json

```
        "mode": {
            "rgb_color": [
                255,
                255,
                255
            ],
        }
```

React.js

```
              {schedules.map(schedule => (
                <div className="each_scheduled" key={schedule.id}>
                  <div>
                    <p className="scheduled_p">Color</p>
                    <p className="scheduled_p">{schedule.mode.rgb_color}</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              ))}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understood your question you can just set the color in inline styling:

```
<p className="scheduled_p" style={{ backgroundColor: `rgb(${schedule.mode.rgb_color.split(',')})` }}></p>
```